# Unexpected behavior while finding and deleting files in Google Drive: file disappears

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I want to find and delete files in Google Drive, which contain special string in the file name.

I tried it in the following way:

1. created a spreadsheet named *testDeleteByName*, where I will run Google App script,
2. created a project in the Cloud Console,
3. activated Google Drive API for the project, created OAuth and added the spreadsheet *testDeleteByName* to this project in the project setting of the spreadsheet.
4. In the spreadsheet I added the script

   ```
     function SearchFiles() {
       var searchFor ='title contains "untitled"';
       var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
     while (files.hasNext()) {
        files.next().setTrashed(true);
        }
     }
   ```
5. Then I created a spreadsheet named *untitled testsheet* to test the script.
6. After this I executed the script in the *testDeleteByName*.

As result I get

1. An error in execution log
   `Exception: Access denied: DriveApp. SearchFiles    @ Code.gs:5`
2. The test file *untitled testsheet* is disappeared (not even in the bin)
3. The file *testDeleteByName* with the script is removed into the bin.

What I'm doing wrong? How looks the correct way?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. At `As result I get`, although an error occurs as `An error in execution log Exception: Access denied: DriveApp. SearchFiles    @ Code.gs:5`, you say `The test file untitled testsheet is disappeared (not even in the bin)` and `The file testDeleteByName with the script is removed into the bin.`. So, I cannot understand your situation. I apologize for this. Can I ask you the detail of your question?

Comment: This is rather strange. Is there any additional code in your script like `emptyTrash()`? Also, is the name of the sheet-bound script "Untitled project"? The `searchFiles()` method counts the name of the script as "one of the names" of the Sheet. So for example if your script is called `Untitled project`, then the `testDeleteByName`  sheet will also be included in the search results, even if it doesn't actually have `untitled` in its own name. I thought that this may be some kind of self-deletion issue but I have not been able to reproduce exactly what you described.